# Figuring out the pod resposible for a specific service

Tags: kubernetes

I have a pod and two services. When I ping one of the service with its name from another pod, I am able to get the response. but not for another service.

```
$ kubectl get pod --show-labels
NAME                            READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE       LABELS
cd-jenkins-6dbdb5c8f9-xcf44     1/1       Running   10         16d       app.kubernetes.io/component=jenkins-master,app.kubernetes.io/instance=cd,app.kubernetes.io/managed-by=Helm,app.kubernetes.io/name=jenkins,helm.sh/chart=jenkins-1.9.17,pod-template-hash=6dbdb5c8f9
```

```
$ kubectl get svc --show-labels
NAME               TYPE        CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)        AGE       LABELS
cd-jenkins         ClusterIP   10.96.192.55   <none>        8080/TCP       16d       app.kubernetes.io/component=jenkins-master,app.kubernetes.io/instance=cd,app.kubernetes.io/managed-by=Helm,app.kubernetes.io/name=jenkins,helm.sh/chart=jenkins-1.9.17
cd-jenkins-agent   ClusterIP   10.96.98.10    <none>        50000/TCP      16d       app.kubernetes.io/component=jenkins-master,app.kubernetes.io/instance=cd,app.kubernetes.io/managed-by=Helm,app.kubernetes.io/name=jenkins,helm.sh/chart=jenkins-1.9.17
```

If I try pinging **cd-jenkins-agent** service from an another pod, it works fine.

But when I try pining **cd-jenkins** service from the same pod, it is not working.

I am wondering **which pod** is rensible for **cd-jenkins-agent** service?

```
$ kubectl exec -it nginx-86c57db685-pnkxx -- sh
# host cd-jenkins
cd-jenkins.default.svc.cluster.local has address 10.96.192.55

# host cd-jenkins-agent
cd-jenkins-agent.default.svc.cluster.local has address 10.96.98.10

# ping -c 2 cd-jenkins
PING cd-jenkins.default.svc.cluster.local (10.96.192.55) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- cd-jenkins.default.svc.cluster.local ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 6ms

# ping -c 2 cd-jenkins-agent
PING cd-jenkins-agent.default.svc.cluster.local (10.96.98.10) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from cd-jenkins-agent.default.svc.cluster.local (10.96.98.10): icmp_seq=1 ttl=61 time=388 ms
64 bytes from cd-jenkins-agent.default.svc.cluster.local (10.96.98.10): icmp_seq=2 ttl=61 time=470 ms
--- cd-jenkins-agent.default.svc.cluster.local ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 2ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 387.755/428.769/469.783/41.014 ms
```

**UPDATE**

Adding more information

```
$ kubectl describe service cd-jenkins-agent                    
Name:              cd-jenkins-agent
Namespace:         default
Labels:            app.kubernetes.io/component=jenkins-master
                   app.kubernetes.io/instance=cd
                   app.kubernetes.io/managed-by=Helm
                   app.kubernetes.io/name=jenkins
                   helm.sh/chart=jenkins-1.9.17
Annotations:       <none>
Selector:          app.kubernetes.io/component=jenkins-master,app.kubernetes.io/instance=cd
Type:              ClusterIP
IP:                10.96.98.10
Port:              slavelistener  50000/TCP
TargetPort:        50000/TCP
Endpoints:         
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>

$ kubectl describe pod cd-jenkins-6dbdb5c8f9-xcf44 |grep -i ip:                            
IP:                 172.17.0.5

$ kubectl describe service cd-jenkins                          
Name:              cd-jenkins
Namespace:         default
Labels:            app.kubernetes.io/component=jenkins-master
                   app.kubernetes.io/instance=cd
                   app.kubernetes.io/managed-by=Helm
                   app.kubernetes.io/name=jenkins
                   helm.sh/chart=jenkins-1.9.17
Annotations:       <none>
Selector:          app.kubernetes.io/component=jenkins-master,app.kubernetes.io/instance=cd
Type:              ClusterIP
IP:                10.96.192.55
Port:              http  8080/TCP
TargetPort:        8080/TCP
Endpoints:         172.17.0.5:8080
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>
```

Manifest content for all the pods:

```
$ kubectl get pod -oyaml

apiVersion: v1
items:
- apiVersion: v1
  kind: Pod
  metadata:
    annotations:
      checksum/config: df1933f788ea761f62ce06ba7b344e4245c42dc7d187cb3055cbfc10921ace86
    creationTimestamp: 2020-03-07T14:16:09Z
    generateName: cd-jenkins-6dbdb5c8f9-
    labels:
      app.kubernetes.io/component: jenkins-master
      app.kubernetes.io/instance: cd
      app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
      app.kubernetes.io/name: jenkins
      helm.sh/chart: jenkins-1.9.17
      pod-template-hash: 6dbdb5c8f9
    name: cd-jenkins-6dbdb5c8f9-xcf44
    namespace: default
    ownerReferences:
    - apiVersion: apps/v1
      blockOwnerDeletion: true
      controller: true
      kind: ReplicaSet
      name: cd-jenkins-6dbdb5c8f9
      uid: c275c986-d0f2-4985-b367-b628149bd89e
    resourceVersion: "113287"
    selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/default/pods/cd-jenkins-6dbdb5c8f9-xcf44
    uid: c402430a-7ded-4aff-b316-e1ca08bac22a
  spec:
    containers:
    - args:
      - --argumentsRealm.passwd.$(ADMIN_USER)=$(ADMIN_PASSWORD)
      - --argumentsRealm.roles.$(ADMIN_USER)=admin
      - --httpPort=8080
      env:
      - name: POD_NAME
        valueFrom:
          fieldRef:
            apiVersion: v1
            fieldPath: metadata.name
      - name: JAVA_OPTS
      - name: JENKINS_OPTS
      - name: JENKINS_SLAVE_AGENT_PORT
        value: "50000"
      - name: ADMIN_PASSWORD
        valueFrom:
          secretKeyRef:
            key: jenkins-admin-password
            name: cd-jenkins
      - name: ADMIN_USER
        valueFrom:
          secretKeyRef:
            key: jenkins-admin-user
            name: cd-jenkins
      image: jenkins/jenkins:lts
      imagePullPolicy: Always
      livenessProbe:
        failureThreshold: 5
        httpGet:
          path: /login
          port: http
          scheme: HTTP
        initialDelaySeconds: 90
        periodSeconds: 10
        successThreshold: 1
        timeoutSeconds: 5
      name: jenkins
      ports:
      - containerPort: 8080
        name: http
        protocol: TCP
      - containerPort: 50000
        name: slavelistener
        protocol: TCP
      readinessProbe:
        failureThreshold: 3
        httpGet:
          path: /login
          port: http
          scheme: HTTP
        initialDelaySeconds: 60
        periodSeconds: 10
        successThreshold: 1
        timeoutSeconds: 5
      resources:
        limits:
          cpu: "2"
          memory: 4Gi
        requests:
          cpu: 50m
          memory: 256Mi
      terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
      terminationMessagePolicy: File
      volumeMounts:
      - mountPath: /tmp
        name: tmp
      - mountPath: /var/jenkins_home
        name: jenkins-home
      - mountPath: /var/jenkins_config
        name: jenkins-config
        readOnly: true
      - mountPath: /usr/share/jenkins/ref/secrets/
        name: secrets-dir
      - mountPath: /usr/share/jenkins/ref/plugins/
        name: plugin-dir
      - mountPath: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount
        name: cd-jenkins-token-w6xtk
        readOnly: true
    dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
    enableServiceLinks: true
    initContainers:
    - command:
      - sh
      - /var/jenkins_config/apply_config.sh
      env:
      - name: ADMIN_PASSWORD
        valueFrom:
          secretKeyRef:
            key: jenkins-admin-password
            name: cd-jenkins
      - name: ADMIN_USER
        valueFrom:
          secretKeyRef:
            key: jenkins-admin-user
            name: cd-jenkins
      image: jenkins/jenkins:lts
      imagePullPolicy: Always
      name: copy-default-config
      resources:
        limits:
          cpu: "2"
          memory: 4Gi
        requests:
          cpu: 50m
          memory: 256Mi
      terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
      terminationMessagePolicy: File
      volumeMounts:
      - mountPath: /tmp
        name: tmp
      - mountPath: /var/jenkins_home
        name: jenkins-home
      - mountPath: /var/jenkins_config
        name: jenkins-config
      - mountPath: /usr/share/jenkins/ref/secrets/
        name: secrets-dir
      - mountPath: /usr/share/jenkins/ref/plugins
        name: plugins
      - mountPath: /var/jenkins_plugins
        name: plugin-dir
      - mountPath: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount
        name: cd-jenkins-token-w6xtk
        readOnly: true
    nodeName: minikube
    priority: 0
    restartPolicy: Always
    schedulerName: default-scheduler
    securityContext:
      runAsUser: 0
    serviceAccount: cd-jenkins
    serviceAccountName: cd-jenkins
    terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
    tolerations:
    - effect: NoExecute
      key: node.kubernetes.io/not-ready
      operator: Exists
      tolerationSeconds: 300
    - effect: NoExecute
      key: node.kubernetes.io/unreachable
      operator: Exists
      tolerationSeconds: 300
    volumes:
    - emptyDir: {}
      name: plugins
    - emptyDir: {}
      name: tmp
    - configMap:
        defaultMode: 420
        name: cd-jenkins
      name: jenkins-config
    - emptyDir: {}
      name: secrets-dir
    - emptyDir: {}
      name: plugin-dir
    - name: jenkins-home
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: cd-jenkins
    - name: cd-jenkins-token-w6xtk
      secret:
        defaultMode: 420
        secretName: cd-jenkins-token-w6xtk
  status:
    conditions:
    - lastProbeTime: null
      lastTransitionTime: 2020-03-24T14:01:22Z
      status: "True"
      type: Initialized
    - lastProbeTime: null
      lastTransitionTime: 2020-03-24T14:02:41Z
      status: "True"
      type: Ready
    - lastProbeTime: null
      lastTransitionTime: 2020-03-24T14:02:41Z
      status: "True"
      type: ContainersReady
    - lastProbeTime: null
      lastTransitionTime: 2020-03-07T14:16:09Z
      status: "True"
      type: PodScheduled
    containerStatuses:
    - containerID: docker://b68b1dc92b9d3ddbc2276b95a14029d6b14d6e19c616b833b8878f2ff43f54f1
      image: jenkins/jenkins:lts
      imageID: docker-pullable://jenkins/jenkins@sha256:7ea1d29c621a10d1e231013f62e32f0eb726dde15a4c219e5010564a6766daa8
      lastState:
        terminated:
          containerID: docker://5b422b334d50502002959b5ab7478eb7aa8d69767fdcca9b39504314e120a347
          exitCode: 143
          finishedAt: 2020-03-24T13:57:24Z
          reason: Error
          startedAt: 2020-03-24T11:10:17Z
      name: jenkins
      ready: true
      restartCount: 11
      started: true
      state:
        running:
          startedAt: 2020-03-24T14:01:26Z
    hostIP: 192.168.99.107
    initContainerStatuses:
    - containerID: docker://63702bb2f84abafffcc3daea86fab5aa8df8989407a03878ff47e235b33a4369
      image: jenkins/jenkins:lts
      imageID: docker-pullable://jenkins/jenkins@sha256:7ea1d29c621a10d1e231013f62e32f0eb726dde15a4c219e5010564a6766daa8
      lastState: {}
      name: copy-default-config
      ready: true
      restartCount: 7
      state:
        terminated:
          containerID: docker://63702bb2f84abafffcc3daea86fab5aa8df8989407a03878ff47e235b33a4369
          exitCode: 0
          finishedAt: 2020-03-24T14:01:21Z
          reason: Completed
          startedAt: 2020-03-24T14:01:11Z
    phase: Running
    podIP: 172.17.0.5
    podIPs:
    - ip: 172.17.0.5
    qosClass: Burstable
    startTime: 2020-03-07T14:16:09Z

- apiVersion: v1
  kind: Pod
  metadata:
    creationTimestamp: 2020-03-07T14:52:54Z
    labels:
      jenkins/cd-jenkins-slave: "true"
      jenkins/label: cd-jenkins-slavex
    name: default-896lw
    namespace: default
    resourceVersion: "18328"
    selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/default/pods/default-896lw
    uid: 47d45a2a-1cc6-4b13-8a1b-b5ec8fb10efd
  spec:
    containers:
    - args:
      - e169f2448e514120084b5e486bcf780a6e7c1bf0eee013c57704b10ebbb1270e
      - default-896lw
      env:
      - name: JENKINS_SECRET
        value: e169f2448e514120084b5e486bcf780a6e7c1bf0eee013c57704b10ebbb1270e
      - name: JENKINS_TUNNEL
        value: cd-jenkins-agent:50000
      - name: JENKINS_AGENT_NAME
        value: default-896lw
      - name: JENKINS_NAME
        value: default-896lw
      - name: JENKINS_AGENT_WORKDIR
        value: /home/jenkins
      - name: JENKINS_URL
        value: http://cd-jenkins.default.svc.cluster.local:8080
      image: jenkins/jnlp-slave:3.27-1
      imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
      name: jnlp
      resources:
        limits:
          cpu: 512m
          memory: 512Mi
        requests:
          cpu: 512m
          memory: 512Mi
      securityContext:
        privileged: false
      terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
      terminationMessagePolicy: File
      volumeMounts:
      - mountPath: /home/jenkins
        name: workspace-volume
      - mountPath: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount
        name: default-token-pbs7v
        readOnly: true
      workingDir: /home/jenkins
    dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
    enableServiceLinks: true
    nodeName: minikube
    nodeSelector:
      beta.kubernetes.io/os: linux
    priority: 0
    restartPolicy: Never
    schedulerName: default-scheduler
    securityContext: {}
    serviceAccount: default
    serviceAccountName: default
    terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
    tolerations:
    - effect: NoExecute
      key: node.kubernetes.io/not-ready
      operator: Exists
      tolerationSeconds: 300
    - effect: NoExecute
      key: node.kubernetes.io/unreachable
      operator: Exists
      tolerationSeconds: 300
    volumes:
    - emptyDir: {}
      name: workspace-volume
    - name: default-token-pbs7v
      secret:
        defaultMode: 420
        secretName: default-token-pbs7v
  status:
    conditions:
    - lastProbeTime: null
      lastTransitionTime: 2020-03-07T14:52:54Z
      status: "True"
      type: Initialized
    - lastProbeTime: null
      lastTransitionTime: 2020-03-07T14:56:35Z
      message: 'containers with unready status: [jnlp]'
      reason: ContainersNotReady
      status: "False"
      type: Ready
    - lastProbeTime: null
      lastTransitionTime: 2020-03-07T14:56:35Z
      message: 'containers with unready status: [jnlp]'
      reason: ContainersNotReady
      status: "False"
      type: ContainersReady
    - lastProbeTime: null
      lastTransitionTime: 2020-03-07T14:52:54Z
      status: "True"
      type: PodScheduled
    containerStatuses:
    - containerID: docker://675283a8493b685d7632276fbe7b5bec8957bc665d05f6bdcca0e647146a3ffd
      image: jenkins/jnlp-slave:3.27-1
      imageID: docker-pullable://jenkins/jnlp-slave@sha256:a5f42dab13d74c079a653408e45cda3ca2bc3483200bbaa44b88fae486ad7e05
      lastState: {}
      name: jnlp
      ready: false
      restartCount: 0
      started: false
      state:
        terminated:
          containerID: docker://675283a8493b685d7632276fbe7b5bec8957bc665d05f6bdcca0e647146a3ffd
          exitCode: 143
          finishedAt: 2020-03-07T14:53:38Z
          reason: Error
          startedAt: 2020-03-07T14:52:55Z
    hostIP: 192.168.99.107
    phase: Failed
    qosClass: Guaranteed
    startTime: 2020-03-07T14:52:54Z
- apiVersion: v1
  kind: Pod
  metadata:
    creationTimestamp: 2020-03-24T11:12:58Z
    generateName: nginx-86c57db685-
    labels:
      app: nginx
      pod-template-hash: 86c57db685
    name: nginx-86c57db685-pnkxx
    namespace: default
    ownerReferences:
    - apiVersion: apps/v1
      blockOwnerDeletion: true
      controller: true
      kind: ReplicaSet
      name: nginx-86c57db685
      uid: e1dfdf35-06a8-4277-948b-9c8538a44cd5
    resourceVersion: "113057"
    selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/default/pods/nginx-86c57db685-pnkxx
    uid: e1e05570-4aba-4c74-8865-6fd2a6c19bff
  spec:
    containers:
    - image: nginx
      imagePullPolicy: Always
      name: nginx
      resources: {}
      terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
      terminationMessagePolicy: File
      volumeMounts:
      - mountPath: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount
        name: default-token-pbs7v
        readOnly: true
    dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
    enableServiceLinks: true
    nodeName: minikube
    priority: 0
    restartPolicy: Always
    schedulerName: default-scheduler
    securityContext: {}
    serviceAccount: default
    serviceAccountName: default
    terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
    tolerations:
    - effect: NoExecute
      key: node.kubernetes.io/not-ready
      operator: Exists
      tolerationSeconds: 300
    - effect: NoExecute
      key: node.kubernetes.io/unreachable
      operator: Exists
      tolerationSeconds: 300
    volumes:
    - name: default-token-pbs7v
      secret:
        defaultMode: 420
        secretName: default-token-pbs7v
  status:
    conditions:
    - lastProbeTime: null
      lastTransitionTime: 2020-03-24T11:12:58Z
      status: "True"
      type: Initialized
    - lastProbeTime: null
      lastTransitionTime: 2020-03-24T14:01:16Z
      status: "True"
      type: Ready
    - lastProbeTime: null
      lastTransitionTime: 2020-03-24T14:01:16Z
      status: "True"
      type: ContainersReady
    - lastProbeTime: null
      lastTransitionTime: 2020-03-24T11:12:58Z
      status: "True"
      type: PodScheduled
    containerStatuses:
    - containerID: docker://a4e00ee2a882cf4e0f8521f97bdb9e9e46b9eee674a83e8b4cd2190b01ecaff1
      image: nginx:latest
      imageID: docker-pullable://nginx@sha256:2539d4344dd18e1df02be842ffc435f8e1f699cfc55516e2cf2cb16b7a9aea0b
      lastState:
        terminated:
          containerID: docker://d53426252c397a50e33cea7c6d9e70ec1967ac3e230e5f790eade209259cf46f
          exitCode: 0
          finishedAt: 2020-03-24T13:57:22Z
          reason: Completed
          startedAt: 2020-03-24T11:13:06Z
      name: nginx
      ready: true
      restartCount: 1
      started: true
      state:
        running:
          startedAt: 2020-03-24T14:01:16Z
    hostIP: 192.168.99.107
    phase: Running
    podIP: 172.17.0.9
    podIPs:
    - ip: 172.17.0.9
    qosClass: BestEffort
    startTime: 2020-03-24T11:12:58Z
kind: List
metadata:
  resourceVersion: ""
  selfLink: ""
```

Manifest for all the services:

```
$ kubectl get svc -oyaml
apiVersion: v1
items:
- apiVersion: v1
  kind: Service
  metadata:
    creationTimestamp: 2020-03-07T14:16:09Z
    labels:
      app.kubernetes.io/component: jenkins-master
      app.kubernetes.io/instance: cd
      app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
      app.kubernetes.io/name: jenkins
      helm.sh/chart: jenkins-1.9.17
    name: cd-jenkins
    namespace: default
    resourceVersion: "13047"
    selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/default/services/cd-jenkins
    uid: aca40b6c-33d0-439d-8398-bde7739ed2f6
  spec:
    clusterIP: 10.96.192.55
    ports:
    - name: http
      port: 8080
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 8080
    selector:
      app.kubernetes.io/component: jenkins-master
      app.kubernetes.io/instance: cd
    sessionAffinity: None
    type: ClusterIP
  status:
    loadBalancer: {}
- apiVersion: v1
  kind: Service
  metadata:
    creationTimestamp: 2020-03-07T14:16:09Z
    labels:
      app.kubernetes.io/component: jenkins-master
      app.kubernetes.io/instance: cd
      app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
      app.kubernetes.io/name: jenkins
      helm.sh/chart: jenkins-1.9.17
    name: cd-jenkins-agent
    namespace: default
    resourceVersion: "13044"
    selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/default/services/cd-jenkins-agent
    uid: 4d8cdb2a-7db8-4e61-8d63-474ad2983ed7
  spec:
    clusterIP: 10.96.98.10
    ports:
    - name: slavelistener
      port: 50000
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 50000
    selector:
      app.kubernetes.io/component: jenkins-master
      app.kubernetes.io/instance: cd
    sessionAffinity: None
    type: ClusterIP
  status:
    loadBalancer: {}
- apiVersion: v1
  kind: Service
  metadata:
    creationTimestamp: 2020-03-07T12:41:08Z
    labels:
      component: apiserver
      provider: kubernetes
    name: kubernetes
    namespace: default
    resourceVersion: "148"
    selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/default/services/kubernetes
    uid: 4881b523-a8e2-4ea5-a826-aa28060eb7a3
  spec:
    clusterIP: 10.96.0.1
    ports:
    - name: https
      port: 443
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 8443
    sessionAffinity: None
    type: ClusterIP
  status:
    loadBalancer: {}
kind: List
metadata:
  resourceVersion: ""
  selfLink: ""
```

Answer (score 1):

If run `kubectl describe svc servicename` it should have `Endpoints` which will have IPs of the pods behind the service.

```
kubectl describe svc kubernetes
Name:              kubernetes
Namespace:         default
Labels:            component=apiserver
                   provider=kubernetes
Annotations:       <none>
Selector:          <none>
Type:              ClusterIP
IP:                10.96.0.1
Port:              https  443/TCP
TargetPort:        6443/TCP
Endpoints:         172.17.0.2:6443
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>
```

If the Endpoints is empty that means the label selector in the service did not match the label on pods.

Comment: I see the service **cd-jenkins-agent** has empty end point, in that case, if I ping, how it is responding for my ping? I have added more info in my question.

Comment: share all service and pod yamls

Comment: I have added manifest for the pods and services for the same, thanks in advance.

Comment: there is no pod responsible for cd-jenkins-agent service because the endpoint is empty...ping will work because the service has an IP...use curl to verify instead of ping..https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-service/